# Error ID: 0 - This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error

Tags: error, customer-community, cookies

I'm trying to insert a script in Customer Community through `Builder > Settings > Advanced > Edit Head Markup` for a cookies popup at the opening of the community.

I've inserted this at the top of HEAD:

```
<script id="Cookiebot" 
        src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js" 
        data-cbid="472bf234-452c-4345-b313-a888365d5c23" 
        data-blockingmode="auto" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

and I've add the url `https://consent.cookiebot.com` to the Trusted Sites for Scripts list (`Builder > Settings > Advanced > Security & Privacy`).

When I save, a popup error shows with the following message

> Try refreshing the page. If that doesn't do the trick, give your
> Salesforce administrator the following error ID, and describe what you
> were trying to accomplish. Error ID: 0 This page has an error. You
> might just need to refresh it. [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.

And the script still doesn't work.
Can anyone help me? Thanks

[image]